# date range validation is valid if 'to date' not in same month as 'from date'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, momentjs

I have search date range 'from date' & 'to date' my validation function make data valid if range of date is not in same month ? for example if from date"2015-06-02" to date "2015-06-01" the range is invalid range? but if I make the to date "2015-05-31" it will be valid range [image: if range in same month][image: if range not in same month]

```
var validateDateRange = function () {
    var fromDate = moment($scope.model.fromDateSearch, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
    var toDate = moment($scope.model.toDateSearch, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
    var a = (fromDate > toDate) ;
    return a;

};
```

> 

Comment: So if your from date is greater than the to date it returns true??

Comment: I would simply compare the JavaScript getTime() values for the dates, making sure the to_date is greater then the from_date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some problem with date format you are passing. So it would also work if you just remove the format and just pass in the value.

Run and check the code snippet below its working fine

```js
var validateDateRange = function (fromDate, toDate) {
    var fromDate = moment(fromDate);
    var toDate = moment(toDate);
    var a = (fromDate > toDate) ;
    return a;

};

var fromDate= new Date("2015-06-02");
var toDate = new Date("2015-06-01");
alert(validateDateRange(fromDate, toDate));

var fromDate= new Date("2015-06-02");
var toDate = new Date("2015-05-31");
alert(validateDateRange(fromDate, toDate));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch, it is safer.

```
var validateDateRange = function () {
    var fromDate = moment($scope.model.fromDateSearch, 'MM-DD-YYYY').valueOf();
    var toDate = moment($scope.model.toDateSearch, 'MM-DD-YYYY').valueOf();
    var a = (fromDate < toDate) ;
    return a;
};
```

Note the 'lower than' sign.